# OnCompletion listener with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player, listener

How do i use the OnCompletion listener for some music?
I would like to press a button to go to another activity that plays some music and then goes back when the music playback is finished. I allready coded the other stuff. I just cant figure out how to use the OnCompletion listener?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You should put the code that should be run when the music is completed in the `OnCompletionListener`, for example:

```
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        finish(); // finish current activity
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

```
mPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer paramMediaPlayer, int paramInt1,int paramInt2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//your code if any error occurs while playing even you can show an alert to user
return true;
}
});
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
//your code if the file was completely played either show an alert to user or start another activity or file.
//even you can finish you activity here
}                   
});
```

Answer (score 6):

I find that above are correct however I was struggling on where to place the code.
See below, i place this code after my code to start the tune!

```
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    mediaPlayer.start();       //Next line is the beginning of where to place the code.
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
      @Override
      public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
      Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "I'm Finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the kotlin version of  setOnCompletionListener :

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener { it // this is MediaPlayer type
                Log.d(TAG,"setOnCompletionListener OnCompletionListener called")
                // do other task
            })
```