# Play sound on button click android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How do I get a button to play a sound from raw when click? I just created a button with id `button1`, but whatever code I write, all is wrong.

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

public class BasicScreenActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_screen);
    }

    Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    MediaPlayer = mp;
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
    zero.setOnCliclListener(new View.OnClickListener() )

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.basic_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Comment: You'd probably want to have the resources managed automatically, so that you can call `MusicManager.getInstance().play(this, R.raw.my_sound);`. If so, this library might be for you: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-Audio

Comment: I'm sorry but your code does not make sense: (1) Where is the code in the middle, it looks like outside any method which is not valid Java, (2) You didn't set any click event on button `one`, (3) Not sure what `zero` refers to as you didn't include the definition in your code, (4) Assuming `zero` is relevant somehow, you've assigned an empty click listener to it, meaning it will do nothing when clicked

Answer (score 272, accepted):

This is the most important part in the code provided in the original post.

```
Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

To explain it step by step:

```
Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

First is the initialization of the button to be used in playing the sound. We use the Activity's [`findViewById`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)), passing the Id we assigned to it (in this example's case: `R.id.button1`), to get the button that we need. We cast it as a `Button` so that it is easy to assign it to the variable `one` that we are initializing. Explaining more of how this works is out of scope for this answer. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14801054/2431281) gives a brief insight on how it works.

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
```

This is how to initialize a [`MediaPlayer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). The MediaPlayer follows the [Static Factory Method Design Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929021/what-are-static-factory-methods). To get an instance, we call its [`create()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context,%20int)) method and pass it the context and the resource Id of the sound we want to play, in this case `R.raw.soho`. We declare it as `final`. Jon Skeet provided a great explanation on why we do so [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4732617/2431281).

```
one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
        //code
    }
});
```

Finally, we set what our previously initialized button will do. Play a sound on button click! To do this, we set the [`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) of our button `one`. Inside is only one method, `onClick()` which contains what instructions the button should do *on click*.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    mp.start();
}
```

To play the sound, we call MediaPlayer's [`start()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#start()) method. This method starts the playback of the sound.

There, you can now play a sound on button click in Android!

---

Bonus part:

As noted in the comment below<sup>Thanks Langusten Gustel!</sup>, and as [recommended in the Android Developer Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#StateDiagram), it is important to call the [`release()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release()) method to free up resources that will no longer be used. Usually, this is done once the sound to be played has completed playing. To do so, we add an [`OnCompletionListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener) to our `mp` [like so:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963033/2431281)

```
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //code
    }
});
```

Inside the `onCompletion` method, we release it [like so:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15046245/2431281)

```
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.release();
}
```

There are obviously **better ways of implementing** this. For example, you can make the MediaPlayer a class variable and handle its lifecycle along with the lifecycle of the `Fragment` or `Activity` that uses it. However, this is a topic for another question. To keep the scope of this answer small, I wrote it just to illustrate *how to play a sound on button click in Android*.

---

### Original Post

First. You should put your statements inside a block, and in this case the onCreate method.

Second. You initialized the button as variable **one**, then you used a variable **zero** and set its onClickListener to an incomplete onClickListener. Use the variable **one** for the setOnClickListener.

Third, put the logic to play the sound inside the onClick.

In summary:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class BasicScreenActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_basic_screen);

        Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And by the Way its one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });       Dont miss that!

Comment: dont't for get to `RELEASE`

Answer (score 49):

The best way to do this is here i found after searching for one issue after other in the LogCat

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_one);
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        mp=null;
    }
});
mp.start();
```

Not **releasing** the Media player gives you this error in LogCat:

> Android: MediaPlayer finalized without being released

Not **resetting** the Media player gives you this error in LogCat:

> Android: mediaplayer went away with unhandled events

So play safe and simple code to use media player.

To play more than one sounds in same Activity/Fragment simply change the resID while creating new Media player like

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_two);
```

and play it !

Have fun!

Answer (score 49):

**Tested and working 100%**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    Context context = this;
    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                try {
                    if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
                    } mp.start();
                } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

*This was all we had to do*

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.release();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
}
```

Comment: This works when replaying the audio as well. When playing sound I think mp.start() will work without the try / catch and if blocks.

Answer (score 10):

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Button one;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
        one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);

        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the result, again nothing works https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xb0lzesp0ibx9z/2.jpg

Comment: You do not need the line mp=new MediaPlayer() because you are initializing it again using MediaPlayer.create(...) on the next line.

Answer (score 8):

- The audio must be placed in the `raw` folder, if it doesn't exists,
  create one.
- The raw folder must be inside the res folder
- The name mustn't have any `-` or special characters in it.

On your activity, you need to have a object `MediaPlayer`, inside the `onCreate` method or the `onclick` method, you have to initialize the `MediaPlayer`, like `MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.name_of_your_audio_file)`, then your audio file ir ready to be played with the call for `start()`, in your case, since you want it to be placed in a button, you'll have to put it inside the `onClick` method.

Example:

```
private Button myButton;
private MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myactivity);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gunshot);

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

there are some predefined sounds: SHUTTER_CLICK, FOCUS_COMPLETE, START_VIDEO_RECORDING, STOP_VIDEO_RECORDING.

Nice!

> MediaActionSound
>
> A class for producing sounds that match those produced by various actions taken by the media and camera APIs. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaActionSound)

use like:

```
fun playBeepSound() {
    val sound = MediaActionSound()
    sound.play(MediaActionSound.START_VIDEO_RECORDING)
}
```

Comment: please provide `Java` version; Your code is in Kotlin

Comment: @PeymanMajidi Java Version  'private void playBeepSound(){
        MediaActionSound sound = new MediaActionSound();
        sound.play(MediaActionSound.START_VIDEO_RECORDING);
    }'

Answer (score 3):

```
Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnB1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v) {
MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.b1);
mp1.start();
}
});
```

Try this i think it will work

Answer (score 3):

**An edge case:**  Above every answer is almost correct but I was stuck in an edge case. If any user randomly clicks the button multiple times within a few seconds then after playing some sound it doesn't respond anymore.

**Reason:** Initialize `Mediaplayer` object is very expensive. It also deals with resources (*audio file*) so it takes some time for it. When users randomly initialize and calling a method of `MediaPlayer`'s methods like `start()`, `stop()`, `release()`, etc can cause `IllegalStateException` which I faced.

**Solution:** Thanks [caw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89818/caw) for his suggestion in the comment about [Android-Audio](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-Audio).
It has just a simple two java classes ([`MusicManager.java`](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-Audio/blob/master/Source/src/im/delight/android/audio/MusicManager.java), [`SoundManager.java`](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-Audio/blob/master/Source/src/im/delight/android/audio/SoundManager.java)).

You can use `MusicManager.java` if you want to play **one-off sound files** -

```
MusicManager.getInstance().play(MyActivity.this, R.raw.my_sound);
```

You can use `SoundManager.java` if you want to play **multiple sounds frequently and fast** -

```
class MyActivity extends Activity {

    private SoundManager mSoundManager;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        int maxSimultaneousStreams = 3;
        mSoundManager = new SoundManager(this, maxSimultaneousStreams);
        mSoundManager.start();
        mSoundManager.load(R.raw.my_sound_1);
        mSoundManager.load(R.raw.my_sound_2);
        mSoundManager.load(R.raw.my_sound_3);
    }

    private void playSomeSound() {
        if (mSoundManager != null) {
            mSoundManager.play(R.raw.my_sound_2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mSoundManager != null) {
            mSoundManager.cancel();
            mSoundManager = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java:

```
private void playBeepSound(){
    MediaActionSound sound = new MediaActionSound();
    sound.play(MediaActionSound.START_VIDEO_RECORDING);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void clickMe (View view) {

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.xxx);
        mp.start();

    }
```

create a button with a method could be called when the button pressed (onCreate),

then create a variable for (MediaPlayer) class with the path of your file

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.xxx);
```

finally run start method in that class

```
mp.start();
```

the file will run when the button pressed, hope this was helpful!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be better if you add some explanation and commenting to your code so future readers can learn from you.

Answer (score 2):

All these solutions "sound" nice and reasonable but there is one big downside. What happens if your customer downloads your application and repeatedly presses your button?

Your `MediaPlayer` will sometimes fail to play your sound if you click the button to many times.

I ran into this performance problem with the `MediaPlayer` class a few days ago.

Is the `MediaPlayer` class save to use? Not always. If you have short sounds it is better to use the `SoundPool` class.

A save and efficient solution is the SoundPool class which offers great features and increases the performance of you application.

SoundPool is not as easy to use as the `MediaPlayer` class but has some great benefits when it comes to performance and reliability.

Follow this link and learn how to use the SoundPool class in you application:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool

[Youtube: Save Solution](https://youtu.be/fIWPSni7kUk)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of resetting it as proposed by DeathRs:

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
       mp.stop();
       mp.release();
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
} mp.start();
```

we can just reset the MediaPlayer to it's begin using:

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
       mp.seekTo(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check if `mp != null` then use the current function:

```
MediaPlayer mpClick;
private void onClickSound() {
    if(mpClick == null){
        mpClick = MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.tap);
    }
    if(mpClick.isPlaying())
    {
    }
    else
    {
        mpClick.start();
    }
}
```

usage:

```
Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnB1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v) {
          onClickSound();
     }
});
```