# Mediaplayer stopped playing my sound - Android studio

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio, android-studio-2.0

So i was trying to do Onclick for all the buttons... whenever the user click some butto it go to OnClickButton , and then play some sound .. for button1 it will play mp1 for button 2 play sound2 ....
so everything work fine but when I clicking a lot on the buttons after a while
the sound just stopped be played .. 
this is the code :

```
public void OnClick(View v) {


    final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
    final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
    final MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
    final MediaPlayer mp4 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound4);

    TextView mytv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMytimer);
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btComp1 || id==R.id.btUser1)
    {
        mytv.setText("Button 1");
        mp1.start();

    }
    if (id == R.id.btComp2 || id==R.id.btUser2)
    {
        mytv.setText("Button 2");
        mp2.start();

    }
    if (id == R.id.btComp3 || id==R.id.btUser3)
    {
        mytv.setText("Button 3");

        mp3.start();

    }
    if (id == R.id.btComp4 || id==R.id.btUser4)
    {
        mytv.setText("Button 4");

        mp4.start();

    }


}
```

I allso disable all casual button sound because all I wanted that will be sound is my sounds ..

```
(disable with setSoundEffectsEnabled(false)
```

Comment: If you don't release your MediaPlayer you can run into troubles. [sud007 addressed that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24569856/5885018).

Comment: @user5890682 if you found my answer below helpful, please accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, don't create a new MediaPlayer in every onClick.  That's completely unnecessary.  Just create them once when the activity starts.

Second, it doesn't look like you're doing anything with MediaPlayer except call its start method.  MediaPlayer has a rather complicated lifecycle you need to observe.  See the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) to understand what you have to understand to make it work correctly.

If all you want to do is quickly trigger some sounds to play in response to buttons, you should probably instead by using a [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) to manage and play all the sounds.  I would definitely prefer that over MediaPlayer for what you're trying to do.  It's much easier to work with.