# Mediaplayer stops working after a while

Tags: android, button, audio, onclick, media-player

I have a soundboard, everything works fine but when I click alot on the buttons after a while the sound just stopped be played .. this is the code :

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{


        //Sounds/Remixes MediaPlayer
        MediaPlayer sound1, sound2, sound3, sound4, remix1, remix2, remix3, remix4;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


            //Sound MediaPlayers
            sound1= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);
            sound2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound2);
            sound3= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound3);
            sound4= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound4);



            //Remixes MediaPlayer
            remix1= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.remix1);
            remix2= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.remix2);
            remix3= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.remix3);
            remix4= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.remix4);




        }

    //Songs stop playing when closing/switching the App
        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            remix1.pause();
            remix2.pause();
            remix3.pause();
            remix4.pause();
            super.onPause();
        }


    //Remix onClick's
    public void remix1(View view){
        if(remix1.isPlaying() == true){
            remix1.pause();
        }else{
            remix1.start();
        }
    }
    public void remix2(View view){
        if(remix2.isPlaying() == true){
            remix2.pause();
        }else{
            remix2.start();
        }
    }
    public void remix3(View view){
        if(remix3.isPlaying() == true){
            remix3.pause();
        }else{
            remix3.start();
        }
    }
    public void remix4(View view){
        if(remix4.isPlaying() == true){
            remix4.pause();
        }else{
            remix4.start();
        }
    }




    //sound onClick's 
    public void sound1(View view){
        sound1.start();
    }
    public void sound2(View view){
        sound2.start();
    }
    public void sound3(View view){
        sound3.start();
    }
    public void sound4(View view){
        sound4.start();
    }

}
```

This is my code with only 4 sounds and 4 remixes.

The sounds are 3 seconds long and the remixes 3 Minutes.

This is my app, you can try it and you'll see sometime the buttons stop working: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aaron.waller.angelasoundboard

The only solution i found was to clean up the MediaPlayer after each use, how can i do that?

Comment: Your onClick looks strange, are they called else where? I would expect to see something more on the lines of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459122/play-sound-on-button-click-android

Answer (score 4):

To clean up media player after each use you should call

```
mediaPlayer.release();
```

But if everything you need is just return mediaPlayer to its state right after `create` method

```
mediaPlayer.reset();
```

should be enough

UPD

In your case add this code to `onCreate` for every mediaPlayer you use.

```
mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.reset();
        //if reset doesnt give you what you need use mp.release() instead
        //but dont forget to call MediaPlayer.create  
        //before next mediaPlayer.start() method

    }
});
```

Comment: @AaronWaller no, after stop for sure or onCompletion

Comment: Please give me an example, i don't get it beceause im new in Android Studio.